# Combine an AppBar with a Drawer in material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an AppBar component and I want to combine it with a drawer, this is the AppBar code:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "material-ui/styles";
import AppBar from "material-ui/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "material-ui/Toolbar";
import Typography from "material-ui/Typography";
import Button from "material-ui/Button";
import IconButton from "material-ui/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "material-ui-icons/Menu";
import TemporaryDrawer from "./Drawer";

const styles = {
  root: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  flex: {
    flex: 1
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: -12,
    marginRight: 20
  },
};

function ButtonAppBar(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <TemporaryDrawer/>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" className={classes.flex}>
            Title
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Drawer</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

ButtonAppBar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ButtonAppBar);
```

Currently I'm using material-ui v1.0.0-beta.33, what I want is to open a drawer on the left side when click on the Button I have in AppBar but I have no idea how to do this.

I'll appreciate the help on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can do it this way - store the boolean value that indicates is the drawer is opened in the state of your component:

```
state = { drawerIsOpen: false }
```

You will change it when user clicks on your Button:

```
  handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ drawerIsOpen: true });
  };
```

Your `render` method should look like this:

```
render() {
  const { classes } = this.props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" className={classes.flex}>
            Title
        </Typography>
          <Button onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen} color="inherit">Drawer</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        variant="persistent"
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
        open={this.state.drawerIsOpen}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
          <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
            <ChevronLeftIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.drawerInner}>
          <p>drawer content</p>
        </div>
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check [this simplified demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/m71po5j269) (see `demo.js` file).